# gdb bug in listing source code

Tags: list, gdb

When I used `l 41` in gdb, the following appears on the screen.  Is this a gdb bug?

```
(gdb) l 41
file: "/home/user1/src/kernel.inc.hpp", line number: 41
file: "/home/user1/src/kernel.inc.hpp", line number: 41
```

GNU gdb (GDB) version: 7.11.1;

gcc version 6.1.1 20160602 (GCC)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a gdb bug?

Yes.

If you had supplied the version of GDB and the compiler you've used to compile your code, this answer could have been more useful.

Comment: I've added the version of GDB and GCC.  Does it help to be more certain that it's a GDB bug?  Thanks!